# Invariant subspaces and their complements

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The following is Exercise 6.4.2 of Conway's Functional Analysis:

Suppose $T\in B(X)$ where $X$ is a Banach space. Prove that $M$ is invariant under $T$ if and only if $M^{\perp}$ is invariant under $T^*$. What does the map $M\to M^{\perp}$ of $Lat T$ into $Lat T^*$ do to the lattice operations? ($Lat T$ is the collection of all invariant subspaces for $T$.)

I'm confused by this exercise. I know that every closed subspace of a Banach space is not complemented. So how can I say for invariant subspace M in a infinite dimensional Banach space , there is a complemented subspace and then show that it's invariant under $T^*$?

And also how can I define the map of $Lat T$ into $Lat T^*$?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful: $M^\perp$ is not a subspace of $X$, but of the dual space $X^*$. The adjoint operator $T^*$ acts on $X^*$, so this makes sense.